# Lighthouse LED simulator

Tags: led, blink, 555

I want to make an LED flash twice every ten seconds to the following character

*

> On 750ms approx, Off 1s , On 750ms approx, Off 7500ms, Repeat.

*

I am fully aware how to do this with a microcontroller but I do not want to go that route.
I was hoping to use 555 timers or similar. Is this possible?
Thanks folks

Comment: possible? maybe. feasible? nah.

Comment: @PlasmaHH  why is that?

Comment: micro is just whacking one in and writing a few lines of code, 5 minute job. using 555s with this sequence is a lot of chaining and adjusting values and tinkering and pot adjustment.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Thanks. Ive a micro controlling 20 leds all in correct sequence. But just thougjt it was a waste of a micro to contol 1 little led ...

Comment: The micros are as cheap, or cheaper. They often come with internal oscillators with as good as 1% accuracy. And you can get them in SOT-23-6 or the usual 8 pin packages. (PIC10F20x part?)

Comment: You could probably simulate it by training fireflys.  It would take slightly longer than designing a 555 circuit, and then the fireflys would eventually die.  All kidding aside, go with an 8-pin microcontroller.  It will be cheaper than the 555, especially with the large caps you will need.

Comment: Any suggestions on  micros??

Comment: attiny, pic, one of the ST cortex parts .. depends what you have a programmer for and whether you want through-hole?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one 555 and a flip-flop, plus a single PNP BJT (or p-channel MOSFET). Low output = ON. Toggle the FF with the 555 output.

The 555 discharge resistor R4 gives you the 750msec 'ON' time. The charge resistor R1 + R4 gives you the 7.5 seconds or 1 second when paralleled with a second resistor (switched by the BJT) R1||R2 + R4.

This is pretty easy. Use a FF compatible with your supply voltage (eg. 4000 series CMOS for >5V or 74HC for <= 5).

Like this (though I'd use a D FF with D tied to /Q rather than the JK Circuitlab has)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frzWq1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or just use a 32-bit micro- using an RTOS should make it easy..

Answer (score 0):

Quite feasible, but a bit fiddly. You need at least two and possibly three timers. And 555 timers aren't great at long times, so you'll have to accept the long period as being somewhere between 6 and 10 seconds not anything more accurate.

Timer 1 should be setup as bistable 'on' for the whole double-blink period and 'off' for the whole long dark period.

Timer 2 should be triggered while timer 1 is on with a 750ms/1000ms cycle, but it should not be self-retriggering.

Then you use some logic gates to light the LED only when both timers are active.

Answer (score 0):

Now if you were prepared to approximate just a little (is anybody going to stand there with a stop-watch?) and use the following sequence

> on 833mS, off 833mS, on 833mS, off 7500mS

then you could use a /12 counter (so an HC163 reloaded with 4 on TC, or 2 HC74's with a gate to make one of them /3) and decode two specific counts to light the LED (in the case of the HC163, you could choose counts 13 and 15 with a 3 NAND gating 2^3, 2^2 and 2^0, or you could economise and make an AND with 3 diodes and a resistor).

I did a very similar thing a few decades ago to create an approximation to a UK ring tone, for an old telephone hacked into an alarm clock.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [CD4017](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snos357a/snos357a.pdf) decade counter/Divider with 10 decoded outputs.

[image]

*Figure 1. The CD4017 decade counter output sequence. Note that only one of the outputs 0 to 9 is on at a time.*

The 4017 can be cascaded to generate any number of steps required.

[image]

*Figure 2. By cascading the 4017 any number of steps can be achieved. Note how the zero output of the first stage resets the second stage which in turn resets the third stage.*

> On 750ms approx, Off 1s , On 750ms approx, Off 7500ms, Repeat.

To get this exact pattern requires a 250 ms clock with 3 + 4 + 3 + 30 = 40 stages or four chips.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9C58T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 3. LED "OR" logic.*

I'm not recommending this other than you can get exactly the sequence you want without programming.